# std::vector no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use the code below for my node editor, I'm using Visual Studio 2019, it errors out whenever I try to insert a node object

edit: forgot that push_back is the correct function, my bad

```cpp
std::vector<Node*> nodes;

void Example(){
    Node* s = new Node();
    nodes.insert(s);
}
```

the full error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector&lt;_Ty, _Alloc>::insert 
[with _Ty=Node *, _Alloc=std::allocator&lt;Node *>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: [A decent `std::vector<T>::insert` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) will be very helpful here. Perhaps [some decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) would also be helpful?

Comment: Can you please explain which overload of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert you want to call with one argument? I don't see an overload which only takes one parameter.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. There's not enough detail / info in this question to provide an answer.

Comment: `vector`'s `insert` methods all take multiple parameters, usually the item to add and the position where the item is to be added. Perhaps you are looking for `push_back`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Must need more coffee. The syntax highlighting made me think it was calling out the argument "list", not the "argument list".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`insert` needs an `iterator` argument for the position where you want to insert an item. E.g.:

```
nodes.insert(nodes.begin(), s);
```

If you don't want to specify the position and just want to append an element to the vector, you could use `push_back`:

```
nodes.push_back(s);
```

Comment: yeah that's my bad, I confused insert with push_back :(

Answer (score 2):

> [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) Inserts elements at the specified
> location in the container-
>
> ```
> iterator insert( iterator pos, const T& value );
> ```

You are not passing an iterator to the position where you want the element to be inserted and hence the error. You could either pass an iterator or use `push_back()` if you want to insert the new element at the end of vector.

So the following would work -

```
nodes.insert(nodes.begin(), s);
```

OR

```
nodes.insert(nodes.end(),s);
```

Or you could use `push_back()` altogether -

```
nodes.push_back(s);
```